# How to apply the same function on different groupings with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame, an aggregation function and k=2 grouping variables.

How can I apply the same aggregation function on the same data frame, with grouping by one variable, the other, both, and neither?

In other words, what is the idiomatic way to implement the following? (k is possibly too large to do this by hand.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(
  mtcars %>%
    summarise(mean(mpg)),
  mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(mean(mpg)),
  mtcars %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarise(mean(mpg)),
  mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl,gear) %>%
    summarise(mean(mpg))
) %>%
  replace_na(list(cyl = 'Any',
                  gear = 'Any'))
#>    mean(mpg) cyl gear
#> 1   20.09062 Any  Any
#> 2   26.66364   4  Any
#> 3   19.74286   6  Any
#> 4   15.10000   8  Any
#> 5   16.10667 Any    3
#> 6   24.53333 Any    4
#> 7   21.38000 Any    5
#> 8   21.50000   4    3
#> 9   26.92500   4    4
#> 10  28.20000   4    5
#> 11  19.75000   6    3
#> 12  19.75000   6    4
#> 13  19.70000   6    5
#> 14  15.05000   8    3
#> 15  15.40000   8    5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: So if k = 4, then grouping would be applied for all the combinations taking 1, 2, 3, 4 at a time ?

Comment: Getting the complete power set would be great, so grouping by {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,3,4}, {2,3,4}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {3,4}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, and no grouping. Once I have the power set, I can always filter the combinations I want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a data.table solution. I know it's not quite what you asked for, but data.table has function for this type of operation, and going through all the permutations on larger data might become quite slow with dplyr.

In the code below an `NA` value in a `by` column represents the inclusion of all values for that column. For example, row 9 is the mean_mpg for all cars with `cyl == 6` -- no condition on `gear`. If you have missing values in the grouping column beforehand, I suggest inserting a placeholder value.

This operation is based on grouping-sets, an idea borrowed from SQL. data.table has 3 functions -- `cube()`, `rollup()` and `groupingsets()` which implement different flavors of this operation. See the [Postgres SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) explanations for further information.

```r
library(data.table)

mtcars_copy <- setDT(copy(mtcars))
cube(mtcars_copy, j = list(mean_mpg = mean(mpg)), by = c("cyl", "gear"))
#>     cyl gear mean_mpg
#>  1:   6    4 19.75000
#>  2:   4    4 26.92500
#>  3:   6    3 19.75000
#>  4:   8    3 15.05000
#>  5:   4    3 21.50000
#>  6:   4    5 28.20000
#>  7:   8    5 15.40000
#>  8:   6    5 19.70000
#>  9:   6   NA 19.74286
#> 10:   4   NA 26.66364
#> 11:   8   NA 15.10000
#> 12:  NA    4 24.53333
#> 13:  NA    3 16.10667
#> 14:  NA    5 21.38000
#> 15:  NA   NA 20.09062
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get all the combinations of `k`

```
library(dplyr)
k <- c('cyl', 'gear', 'am')

c(mtcars %>% summarise(mean(mpg)), 
      purrr::map(seq_along(k), ~combn(k, .x, function(y) 
       mtcars %>% group_by_at(y) %>% summarise(mean(mpg)), simplify = FALSE))) 


#$`mean(mpg)`
#[1] 20.09

#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl `mean(mpg)`
#  <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     4        26.7
#2     6        19.7
#3     8        15.1

#[[2]][[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  gear `mean(mpg)`
#  <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     3        16.1
#2     4        24.5
#3     5        21.4

#[[2]][[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     am `mean(mpg)`
#  <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     0        17.1
#2     1        24.4

#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl  gear `mean(mpg)`
#  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     4     3        21.5
#2     4     4        26.9
#3     4     5        28.2
#4     6     3        19.8
#5     6     4        19.8
#6     6     5        19.7
#7     8     3        15.0
#8     8     5        15.4
#.....
#.....
```

The first part `mtcars %>% summarise(mean(mpg))` is `mean` without any grouping whereas rest of them are grouped with all possible combinations with different lengths.